# How to check whether data exists and insert by one query in websql?

Tags: cordova, web-sql

Can I have one full query to check whether the data has been in database and insert it if not?

I believe this can be done in normal SQL by using `TRANSACTION`.

The consideration is not to do the manual `SELECT` query then `INSERT` is I have more than 1 table to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WebSQL is an implementation of SQLite, you could use `INSERT OR IGNORE` to manage [conflict resolution](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) in a single transaction.

For example, if you had the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_id INTEGER, track_id INTEGER, value INTEGER);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX data_idx ON data(event_id, track_id);
```

Which already contained data:

```
1|1|2|3
2|2|3|4
```

You could issue the following sequential statements:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data VALUES (NULL, 1, 2, 3);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data VALUES (NULL, 2, 3, 5);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data VALUES (NULL, 3, 4, 5);
```

And the result of `SELECT * FROM data` would be:

```
1|1|2|3
2|2|3|4
3|3|4|5
```

The existing rows will not be updated because of the constraint violation, but the first 2 statements will be ignore instead of fail, so the third will execute successfully and the third row will be inserted.

Comment: Wow I have been using sqlite for years but just know this feature from you! Thanks!